# How can I multiply a string in the C language?

Tags: c, cs50

I want to "multiply" a string by an `int` variable that the user inputs.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

    // Height < 24

    string block = "#";
    string output;

    int main(void) {
        printf("Height: ");
        int height = GetInt();
        while (true) { 
            if (height < 24 && height > 0) {
                output = "#" + block * height;
                printf("%s\n", output); 
                break;

            } else {
                printf("Height: ");
                height = GetInt();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Using the `Height` variable I want to multiply the string variable `block (#)` by `Height`, and add that to another `"#"`.

I tried implementing it in the only way I could think of it making sense however it doesnt seem the syntax is right.

I've looked over StackOverflow on this subject and can only find C# and C++ topics with this question in mind.

EDIT: After being printed the output should look like this:

```
       ##
      ###
     ####
    #####
   ######
  #######
 ########
#########
```

And the lines of "#" being outputted depends on the Height variable that the user inputs. Say the user inputs a height of "5":

```
Height: 5
       ##
      ###
     ####
    #####
   ######
```

Should be output.

Comment: you cannot _multiply_ a _string_. Period.

Comment: Unclear for me: what does it mean to *multiply string*?  ASCII code for `#`? Or you want `#` to be a substitution value? (then use a function)

Comment: How did you get `string` in `C` ?

Comment: I assume "multiplying a string" means "I want n # symbols in a string." C doesn't define *string* so I don't know what types those are and where cs50.h comes from. Normally you'd just use a char array and add as many #s as you want.

Comment: @Minato It's a kind of magic ;) It is *not* a `std::string`! Look at `<cs50.h>`: [`typedef char *string;`](https://mirror.cs50.net/library50/c/cs50-library-c-3.0/cs50.h)

Comment: allocate memory block like `output = malloc(height + 1)` and `memset(output, '#', height); output[height] = 0;printf("%s\n", output);free(output);`

Comment: @John_West I am bit rusty.. you need to use `char*` for `string` like functionality.. or `typedef`

Comment: @Minato I assume he is using [this library](https://manual.cs50.net/library/) which has a `typedef` in it.

Comment: could you show us how should look that string after you "multiply" it

Comment: he does not mean 'multiply' in numerical sense, he wants a 'duplicate'

Comment: You mean here `printf("%s\n", output);` the output should print `#` 24 times ? like this `########################`

Comment: After being "Multiplied" It should look like        ##
      ###
     ####
    #####
   ######
  #######
 ########
#########

Comment: @TylerW please edit your question instead of posting comments. And please explain the logic behind this.

Comment: @TylerW, OK now your question is a bit clearer.  But it's still unclear how many lines of "##" you want.

Comment: @TylerW  There is no any need to "multiply" a string that to output the figure you showed. Also what about strings containing several characters? How should the figure look fro example string "123"?

Comment: This may be because this is from a problem set for a class in CS.

Comment: @TylerW I hope you have at least learned how to ask questionss.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you need 2 loops to do this. One for iterating through the characters you want to print on a line, one to iterate through the entire height (number of lines).

So what we want to do is:

- Go through each line from 1 up to and including the height.
- For each line, output as many #'s as the current line number

e.g.

```
 int lineno;
 int height  = GetInt();
 ... 
 for (lineno = 1; lineno <= height; lineno++) {
      int column;
      for (column = 0; column < lineno; column++) {
           putchar('#');
      }
     putchar('\n');
 }
```

This will be a left adjusted tree. I'll leave it up to you to right adjust it, i.e. print spaces in front of the '#', or start by printing 2 #'s instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

You don't multiply a string, you simply use a loop and output the character repeatedly.

```
int j;
for (j = 0; j < (1 + height); ++j) {
    printf ("#");  /* Or putchar('#') */
}
printf ("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Although C++ is not Python, you could try and implement a function that imitates string multiplication using string concatenation, like so:

```
string strmltply (string s, int multiplier) {
    string res;

    strcpy(res, s);

    // concatenate s (multiplier - 1) times
    for (int i = 1; i < multiplier; ++i) {
        strcat(res, s);
    }

    return res;
}
```

and then use it in a loop over the `multiplier` in your program, where each iteration you print the wanted string (in your case `#`) and then add a newline character `\n`.

Comment: This will segfault with a probability of about 1-1E-6.